# Is it possible to receive User Data Streams and Websocket Market Streams in one stream (Binance Futures API)?

Tags: c#, websocket, binance

The Binance Futures API documentation specifies how to get User Data Streams and Websocket Market Streams data separately, in separate streams.
The documentation also describes how to subscribe to receive combined Websocket Market Streams data (several subscriptions to Websocket Market Streams in one stream).
But I couldn't find information how to subscribe to receive User Data Streams and Websocket Market Streams in one stream.

https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/futures/en/#user-data-streams

https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/futures/en/#websocket-market-streams

Comment: No, binance just doesn't provide such functionality.  User data stream is private. In practice, AFIAK, most trading systems handle market data stream and user stream separately.

Comment: I would like to note that Websocket Market Data Streams can be obtained via wss://fstream-auth.binance.com/ws/<streamName>?listenKey=<validateListenKey> and User Data Streams via wss://fstream-auth.binance.com/ws/<listenKey>?listenKey=<validateListenKey>.
To get listenKey it is necessary to make POST request with your API-key. So the privacy level of these data is the same.

Comment: I was able to get data from Websocket Market Streams and User Data Streams in one stream.
I used the following to connect.
string streamName1 = "trxusdt@bookTicker";
string streamName2 = listenKey;
Url = new Uri($"wss://fstream-auth.binance.com/stream?streams={streamName1}/{streamName2}&listenKey={listenKey}");
That is, instead of streamName2 in the combined Websocket Market Streams, I used listenKey.
The response structure is the same as in normal combined Websocket Market Streams: {"stream":"<streamName>", "data":<rawPayload>}.

Comment: Please provide your answer as an answer instead of a comment.

Answer (score 1):

To get Websocket Market Streams and User Data Streams in one stream, a combined stream can be used. The URL template for the combined stream looks like this:

```
$"wss://fstream-auth.binance.com/stream?streams={streamName1}/{streamName2}/{streamName3}&listenKey={listenKey}"
```

A valid `listenKey` must be entered in place of one of `streamName`. For example:

```
string streamName1 = "trxusdt@bookTicker";  
url = new Uri($"wss://fstream-auth.binance.com/stream?streams={streamName1}/{listenKey}&listenKey={listenKey}");
```

The resulting data has the same view as a typical combined stream:

```json
{"stream": streamName, "data": rawPayload}
```

Keep in mind that this feature is not documented—or, at least, I didn't find this feature in the official Binance API documentation.